# Search functionality for date field column in Jqgrid With in range(From - To)

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I need to filter records within range of dates.

I tried this code but it doesn't work.

I added just one datePicker, I am not able to add Range of Date.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function () {
            <jqgrid:grid id="records" url= "'${createLink(action:'list')}'"
                colNames="'ID','Status','Created Date','Last Updated'"
                colModel="
                    {name:'Id',index: 'id', width:'150'},
                    {name:'status', width:'105'},               
                    {name:'dateCreated',search:true,sortable:true, formatter:'date',formatoptions: { srcformat: 'ISO8601Long', newformat:'M d, Y H:i'},searchoptions:{dataInit:datePick}},
                    {name:'lastUpdated',search:false,sortable:false, formatter:'date',formatoptions: { srcformat: 'ISO8601Long', newformat:'M d, Y H:i'}}"
                 sortname="'dateCreated'"
                 sortorder ="'desc'"
                 caption="'&nbsp;'"
                 height="'auto'"
                 width="800"
                 rowNum="30"
                 autowidth="true"
                 viewrecords="true"
                 showPager="true"
                 datatype="'json'">

                <jqgrid:filterToolbar id="records" searchOnEnter="false" />
                <jqgrid:navigation id="records" add="false" edit="false" del="false" search="false" refresh="false"/>
                <jqgrid:refreshButton id="records" />
            </jqgrid:grid>


        });

        datePick = function(elem)
        {
           jQuery(elem).datepicker({changeYear: true,
               changeMonth: true});
        }
 </script>
```

Comment: I think you should do the filter by your own logic and have the filter controls outside of jqgrid. What version of jqgrid you are using?

Comment: Have you found the solution or still looking for it?

Comment: I am using jqgrid version is jqgrid:3.8.0.1

Comment: i am not finding any solution ,still trying to fix.